# Error during reading and writing test file in simple MPI code

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI code where processes read a binary file and write it back again. The way the data is distributed is that process 0 reads (and then writes) the first half of the file whereas process 1 reads (and then writes) the second half of the file. The issue here now is that the input and the output files do not match (diff shows that they differ). If there is only 1 process, everything works ok. Can someone point out what is going wrong?

Using OpenMPI, compiled as: mpicc -Wall test_mpi.c -o test_mpi 
Run as: mpirun -np 2 ./test_mpi

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int rank, np, i;  //np = no. of processes
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    int filesize = 48*1048576;  //input filesize 48MB

    double *data = (double*) malloc (filesize/np);
    FILE* fpa;
    fpa = fopen ( "512_featurevec.out", "rb");
    fseek(fpa, filesize/np*rank, SEEK_SET);
    printf("read: %d\n", (int)fread(&data[0], sizeof(double), filesize/(np*sizeof(double)), fpa));
    fclose(fpa);

    char* outfile = "outfile.txt";
    for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
        if(rank == i) {
            fpa = fopen ( outfile, "ab");
            fseek(fpa, filesize/np*rank, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite ( &data[0], sizeof(double), filesize/(np*sizeof(double)), fpa);
            fclose ( fpa );
        }   
    }   

    free(data);
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please don't cast the pointer returned by malloc( ). You don't need to touch it at all and, if you do, you could be allowing bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, but this works:

```
char* outfile = "outfile.txt";
    for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
        if(rank == i) {
            fpa = fopen ( outfile, "ab");
            fseek(fpa, filesize/np*rank, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite ( &data[0], sizeof(double), filesize/(np*sizeof(double)), fpa);
            fclose ( fpa );
        } 
        MPI_Barrier(comm);  
    }
```

For some reason, if proc 1 arrives before proc 0 and fseeks an empty file to some value, it *does* position the file pointer to the correct offset (verified by ftell), but writes from offset 0 only. (I must be doing something trivially wrong, but anyway).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue is due to the fact that each child is opening the file for writing, which leads to contention.

Try having the file name depend on the rank (for example, writing to `out file.txt.(rank)` and see if all of the outputs match up.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I had been scratching my head without making any progress until I read this post. So simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using MPI and going to the trouble of using seek to partition up the file, rather than using POSIX I'd suggest using MPI-IO (standard as part of MPI2, c. 1996 or so): Good references are:

- http://www.mhpcc.edu/training/workshop2/mpi_io/MAIN.html
- http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/B673/node179.html

and at our centre we have the first part of this, which I think is pretty good:

- https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/a/aa/ParIO-HPCS2011.pdf

An MPI-IOed version of your code above is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int rank, np;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    const int filesize = 48*1048576;  //input filesize 48MB
    const int ndoubles = filesize/(sizeof(double)*np);
    double *localdata = malloc(ndoubles*sizeof(double));

    /* create a type which describes our view of the file --
     * in particular, just our subarray of the global array
     */
    int globalsizes[1] = {filesize};
    int localsizes[1] = {ndoubles};
    int starts[1] = {ndoubles*rank};

    MPI_Datatype fileview;
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1, globalsizes, localsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &fileview);
    MPI_Type_commit(&fileview);

    /* read in only our data */
    MPI_File fpa;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "512_featurevec.out", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fpa);

    /* note could use MPI_File_seek instead of file set view */
    MPI_File_set_view(fpa, (MPI_Offset)0, MPI_DOUBLE, fileview, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_read_all(fpa, localdata, ndoubles, MPI_DOUBLE, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&fpa);

    /* write out data - it will have same layout, we're just writing instead of erading*/

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "output.dat", MPI_MODE_WRONLY|MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fpa);

    /* note could use MPI_File_seek instead of file set view */
    MPI_File_set_view(fpa, (MPI_Offset)0, MPI_DOUBLE, fileview, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write_all(fpa, localdata, ndoubles, MPI_DOUBLE, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&fpa);

    free(localdata);
    MPI_Type_free(&fileview);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I quickly wanted to measure the speedup of I/O, hence I tried to parallelize fwrite as I showed. But I agree, MPI_IO is definitely a better way.

Comment: You can use MPI_File_seek (or MPI_File_write_at) in a very similar way to what you've already got, and it will have better semantics (eg, won't act weirdly if someone else moves the file pointer...)